# Enabling logging in Embedded Tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, embedded-tomcat-8

I'm rather new to the whole embedded tomcat setup. I'm working on a project that embeds tomcat in an application which I further wish to deploy as a java web start file.
So I get this one error which requires me to check logging and having no previous experience I have absolutely no clue how to.
If any of you'll could help me out it would be amazing.
I'm using eclipse photon with inbuilt maven.

Thanks,
Noel

My application code...

```
package com.TomCat.EmbTC;

import java.io.File;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;

public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) throws LifecycleException, 
InterruptedException,
ServletException {
String docBase = "src/main/webapp/";

Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
String webPort = System.getenv("PORT");
    if(webPort == null || webPort.isEmpty()) {
        webPort = "8111";
    }
    tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf(webPort));

tomcat.addWebapp("/", new File(docBase).getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println("configuring app with basedir: " + new File("./" + 
docBase).getAbsolutePath());

tomcat.start();
tomcat.getServer().await();  
}
}
```

My pom.xml file...

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.TomCat</groupId>
<artifactId>EmbTC</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>EmbTC Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <tomcat.version>8.5.5</tomcat.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>   

<dependency>
<groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
</dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
 <finalName>EmbTC</finalName>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: Whats the error you're getting?

Comment: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start